# How to Test for Some Basic Assumptions of (Zero Inflated) Negative Binomial?

Tags: panel-data, stata, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data, zero-inflation

I am currently working with a T dominant panel --time-series cross-section dataset-- that has N = 8 (eight European countries) and T = 28 (28 quarters for each country). The dependent variable --bailout conditionality-- is a non-negative count integer variable --the number of measures to be applied in each quarter--, with excess of 0s (66.67%) and a lot of over-dispersion (with mean = 4.74 and standard deviation = 12.23, as well as a Pearson dispersion statistic over 12). There are just 4 regressors, the one of interest and three controls.

I am am estimating my model using Zero Inflated Negative Binomial regression due to over-dispersion and excess of zeroes (notice that I have strong theoretical reasons to assume that two different process generate the zeroes). However, there are some assumptions I'd like to test but that I do not know how to test.

First, I'd like to check that errors are serially and contemporaneously independent, but I am not sure how to do it. For serial correlation, I have thought of testing if the lagged error in the predicted number of counts helps us explain the present error in the predicted number of counts. However, I do not know if this is a valid approach. And even if it is, I do not know if it is the best way to check for serial independence of the errors. The other possible violation of error independence is contemporaneous correlation. Does anyone know how to test if errors are not contemporaneously independent in my circumstances? I have thought of visually inspecting the errors with a scatterplot of residuals against fitted values, but is this the best strategy?

Second, I'd like to know if, in a ZINB model, the only way that I have to take into account time-persistent unobserved heterogeneity is by including unit dummies. Or, in other words, is it possible to do random effects in a ZINB model? And, if it is, how to choose between fixed and random? The Hausman test would usually do the trick, but with a non-negative count as a dependent variable I don't really know it. Any suggestions here?

Finally, my last doubt is about heteroskedasticity. As far as I am concerned, negative binomial models do not assume honoskedasticity, am I right? Thus, I do not need to test if error variance is constant or not, true?

PS: I am using Stata. Thank you all for your time and patience.

Comment: You can add random effects to ZINB models, however I haven't used ZINB models myself so the only thing I can do to help you is to refer you to a book I started to read from Zuur et al (2012) Zero Inflated Models and Generalized Linear Mixed Models with R. Link = http://www.highstat.com/book4.htm

Comment: Thank you very much, it's a good start. Ideally, I'm looking for Stata coding solutions though, since R and I are not (yet) good friends. I forgot to mention it in the original question, my apologies.

Comment: The book should still give you some valuable info on ZINB models but unfortunately it won't help you much for building it in Stata. Good luck!